# how to find min value from array of objects over multiple keys in single function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have to find  min value from an array of objects but I have multiple keys and I want to find the min value of all keys or specified keys.

> For example

```
var users = [
    {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:30, height: 75, weight: 83},
    {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:24, height: 63, weight: 75},
    {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:27, height: 56, weight: 55}
]
```

In this example, I want to find the users with min age, height and weight.
But by using a single function.

> I am using this function. its finds min age only.

```
findMin(data) {
        return data.reduce((min, u) => u.age < min ? u.age : min, data[0].age);
    },
```

Comment: What is the importance criteria with _min_ values? I mean if person is younger but taller than other, which one comes first? Or are they grouped in separate arrays? Please, be more specific

Comment: A user with the lowest age, weight, and height.

Comment: And it is a possibility to have multiple users for example.             function should return  three different uses  1 user with lowest age, 1 user with lowest height and 1 user with lowest weight

Comment: From objects of the array you want to find one person with min age one with min weight and one with min-height is that what you meant ?

Comment: Yes, you are  right.

Comment: Please provide the expected result with different input data

Comment: Your code isn't quite a [mre] because it doesn't show exactly what output you expect; describing it in words is nice but not explicit. I can guess, but I'm not sure. Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3Xa3W) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: From  example above I am expecting     `user = {
        weight: {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:27, height: 56, weight: 55},
        height: {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:27, height: 56, weight: 55},
        age: {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:24, height: 63, weight: 75}
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```js
const users = [ {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:30, height: 75, weight: 83}, {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:24, height: 63, weight: 75}, {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:27, height: 56, weight: 55} ];
const min = (arr, key) => arr.reduce((min, el) => el[key] < min[key] ? el : min);
const keys = ['age', 'height', 'weight'];
const result = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, min(users, k)]));
console.log(result)
```

Using only 1 function :

```js
const users = [ {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:30, height: 75, weight: 83}, {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:24, height: 63, weight: 75}, {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:27, height: 56, weight: 55} ];

const min = (arr, keys) => arr.reduce(
  (min, el) => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, el[k] < min[k][k] ? el : min[k]])), 
  {age: arr[0], height: arr[0], weight: arr[0]}
 );

const result = min(users, ['age', 'height', 'weight']);
console.log(result)
```

Output :

```
{
    age: { minAgeItem },
    weight: { minWeightItem },
    height: { minHeightItem }
}
```

Comment: @nemOz  it working but as I mention in my question. Is there any possibility to perform a single function? In your example, you are using a map, and then for each property, it's iterating the array every time. that I don't want to do because of performance issues.

Comment: Edited, I let you check the second `code sample`

Answer (score 0):

This is my modified version!

```js
const arr = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "ABC",
    age: 30,
    height: 75,
    weight: 83
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "ABC",
    age: 24,
    height: 63,
    weight: 75
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "ABC",
    age: 27,
    height: 56,
    weight: 55
  }
];

function getMins(array) {
  let minAge = Infinity,
    minHeight = Infinity,
    minWeight = Infinity;
  const output = [{}, {}, {}];
  array.forEach((user) => {
    if (user.age <= minAge) {
      minAge = user.age;
      output[0] = user;
    }
    if (user.height <= minHeight) {
      minHeight = user.height;
      output[1] = user;
    }
    if (user.weight <= minWeight) {
      minWeight = user.weight;
      output[2] = user;
    }

  });
  return output;
}

console.log(getMins(arr));
```

Comment: I think they want to get min value for each field, not sort the array based on those values

Comment: @adiga Thanks answered without reading properly!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you well, that you want to extract min value for each of fields. Then you could expand your functions to return an object like this:

Note: open chrome console and check output, SO console is giving some weird results!

```js
var users = [
    {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:30, height: 75, weight: 83},
    {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:24, height: 63, weight: 75},
    {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:27, height: 56, weight: 55}
]

function findMin(data) {
  return data.reduce((mins, u) => {
    mins['minAge'] = (u.age < mins['minAge'] ? u.age : mins['minAge']);
    mins['minHeight'] = (u.height < mins['minHeight'] ? u.height : mins['minHeight']);
    mins['minWeight'] = (u.weight < mins['minWeight'] ? u.weight : mins['minWeight']);
    return mins
  }, {
    minAge: data[0].age,
    minHeight: data[0].height,
    minWeight: data[0].weight
  });
}

console.log(findMin(users))
```

edit:
Added more flexibility to the function:

```js
var users = [
{ id: "1", name: "ABC", age: 30, height: 75, weight: 83 },
  { id: "1", name: "ABC", age: 24, height: 63, weight: 75 },
  { id: "1", name: "ABC", age: 27, height: 56, weight: 55 }
];

function findMin(data, keys) {
  return data.reduce((mins, u) => {
    keys.forEach(
      (key) => (mins[key] = u[key] < mins[key] ? u[key] : mins[key])
    );
    return mins;
  }, keys.reduce((accumulator, value) => {
    return {...accumulator, [value]: data[0][value]};
  }, {}));
}

console.log(findMin(users, ['age','height']));
```

Comment: Why not add the index or ID  of the person to each?

Comment: You are forgetting `id` property. Though good approach. Instead of setting values, check for values and return the lesser one. Also, OP is looking for user and not minimum values

Comment: @Komiii, Thank for you your answer. Are there any possibilities to make this dynamically? for example, I don't know how many keys are there that I have to use to find Min.

Comment: Like we can pass an array of fields.   var fields = ['weight', 'age', 'height', ........ ]

Comment: And then it calculate for all the provided fields.

Comment: @IftakharAhmed I've added more flexible solution, you can check the post now

Answer (score 0):

Another one approach

```js
const users = [
    {id:"1", name:"ABC", age:30, height: 75, weight: 83},
    {id:"2", name:"ABC", age:24, height: 63, weight: 75},
    {id:"3", name:"ABC", age:27, height: 56, weight: 55},
];

const getMinsBy = (users, properties) => {
  const minBy = (prop) => users.reduce((min, curr) => (min[prop] > curr[prop]) ? curr : min)
  
  return properties.reduce((acc, prop) => ({ ...acc, [prop]: minBy(prop) }), {});
};

console.log(getMinsBy(users, ['age', 'height', 'weight']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the below statement you can sort the array based on age, height and weight:

```
objs.sort((a,b)=> (a.age - b.age || a.height - b.height || a.weight - 
 b.weight));
```

Using the above logic, you can append how many ever sort columns you might need in the order you need them.

The above statement is same as below SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM OBJS ORDER BY NAME,AGE,ROLLNO;
```

I would also suggest to sort this at backend only instead of frontend as to reduce complexity at frontend.